# Can't retrieve SIM and IMEI number of phone in android 11

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to retrieve SIM and IMEI number from android phone. In android 9 or lower version i can retrieve it properly but on update version it crush app and can't retrieve phone number. I need this because to identify right mobile where opt and my app installed. My source code look likes.

```
 TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    String simID = telephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber();
    String telNumber = telephonyManager.getSubscriberId();
    String IMEI = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

I also add necessary permission like.

```
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, "android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE") != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{"android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"}, 111);

        return false;
        }
```

Also i add READ_PHONE_STATE and READ_PHONE_NUMBERS permission.

Answer (score 1):

From Android 10 and above you need "READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE" permission to read IMEI. But that permission is only granted to system apps. So there's no way to retrieve IMEI in Android 10 or above.

[Please refer documentation: https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/data-identifiers#device-ids](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#data-ids)

[Read this too](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/device-identifiers)

Answer (score 0):

In new devices use `Device ID` instead

```
String dev_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                    Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```